Problem with out of stock products on dropdown Magento 2
I have a problem because for some reason, products that are out of stock are displayed in dropdown on the product page in Magento 2. I would like those that are out of stock to be gray. I don't know why this option disappeared. My magento version is 2.4.6-p3
I don't know how to fix that.
